# UIRotationGestureRecognizer changes with CGAffineTransformMakeScale

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, cgaffinetransformscale

A view is flipped using this:

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);  // self is an UIView
```

To rotate this view:

```
-(void)handleRotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.rotation);
    recognizer.rotation = 0;
}
```

The issue is that after the view is flipped so is the rotation's direction.  Any solution how to fix this?

Edit: My current solution is using a boolean and negate the recognizer.rotation value in handleRotate method.  But I am still looking for the technical solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try `self.transform.a * recognizer.rotation` ?
If I understand correctly the AffineTransform, the X scaling is store at `a`.

[CGAffineTransform Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) Look for `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` and `CGAffineTransformMake`